# Complex multiplication as a "spiral similarity", quaternions

Tags: complex-numbers, rotations

Unit complex numbers represent rotations in 2D.
In general, multiplication by a complex number corresponds to a [spiral similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_similarity) (twist and zoom) centered at the origin of the complex plane. This a two-parameter transformation.

Naively, a spiral similarity centered at the origin in 3D seems to be a four-parameter transformation; two parameters to define the axis, one scale factor and one angle. In fact this is a "double cover" because of antipodal points representing the same axis, AFAICS.

I know that representing 3D rotations with unit quaternions does *NOT* work like this—but is it valid to observe that a 3D spiral similarity centred at the origin has four degrees of freedom, like a quaternion? Apologies for the informality of this.

Comment: I discover the term "spiral similarities" ; I was accustomed to "**similitude transformations**" ; I don't see any spiral (though I understand that the spiral can appear when there are iterations). But if Wikipedia uses it, it's like if God was saying it...